# Knex Insert and onConflict is not a function

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I tried to add a simple upsert using knex. And the recommended way is (for postgres) to use onConflict. The original code that works (except for the updating part):

```
const dbObject = db();
await dbObject('names')
  .insert({key: key, name: name});
```

So I updated it according to what I see in the [manual](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-onConflict):

[image]

```
const dbObject = db();
await dbObject('names')
  .insert({key: key, name: name})
  .onConflict('key')
  .merge();
```

However, this gave the following error:

> *TypeError: dbObject(...).insert(...).onConflict is not a function*

Which to me is quite a mystery, since I am using the correct version:

> *npm view knex version*
>
> *0.95.0*

And the knex db object is created basically by (config is loaded from a file):

```
const knex = knexBuilder({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: config,
  pool: {min: 0, max: maxConnections},
});
return knex
```

What is causing the error, how is onConflict not a function?

Comment: Check in node_modules folder that the knex version is correct

Comment: Yes @felixmosh it is correct

Comment: Important to note that `npm view knex version` prints the latest available version of the package, NOT the version you have installed. For that you should run `npm list knex`

Comment: Only PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite implement `onConflict`, see http://knexjs.org/#Builder-onConflict. Perhaps you are using a different `client` in your knex config? This is working just fine for me on knex@0.95.4 with `client: 'pg'`.